# Leading and Trailing

Tags: number-theory

### last 3 digit and first 3 digit

given $n$ and $k$ , How can I find the first 3 digit and last 3 digit of $n^k$ ?
$n<=2^31$ and $k<=10^7.$
You can assume that the input is given such that $n^k$ contains at least six digits.

Comment: That's very simple: First three digits are $\Bigl\lfloor\frac{n^k}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(n^k)\rfloor-3}}\Bigl\rfloor$. Last $3$ digits are $n^k\bmod{10^3}$.

Comment: I am clear about the 2nd answer but how can I obtain the formula for first 3 digit?

Comment: @jameselmore: You've made a mistake in your edit on $2^{31}$ (curly brackets needed around the "$31$").

Answer (score 1):

Turning a comment into an answer...

**First (most significant) $3$ digits:**

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n^k}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(n^k)\rfloor-2}}\right\rfloor$$

**Last (least significant) $3$ digits:**

$$n^k\bmod{10^3}$$

Comment: I can not understand the formula for first 3 digit. please explain how can I obtain the formula. @barak manos

Comment: @MSHossain: $\lfloor\log_{10}(n^k)\rfloor$ gives you the number of digits in your input number $n^k$ (the number of digits minus one, to be more accurate). Do you understand now?

Comment: Its clear now. thanks @barak manos

Comment: @MSHossain: You're welcome. Please note that I've fixed a slight mistake which gives you the first $4$ (instead of $3$) digits. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Comment: yes . your formula gives the first four digit. for 3 digit I have to  Substruct  2 instead of 3. am I right? @barak manos

Comment: @MSHossain: Yes, that's what I fixed.